# How can i add Write protected access to an excel in linux

Tags: linux, excel

I have a ETL job that creates the excel file and puts into one of the unix directory.

I have an unix "mailx -s" command to send that excel as an attachemnt.

I am looking for a way to extend my program or script to make the Excel file write protected before sending it in mail. The program/script should run on Linux/Unix ?

Is there any way.. Please suggest.

Comment: The best than can be done, is to cryptographicly sign a file. That way you can know if it changes. There may be snake-oil programs that can do this in MS-Windows, by setting a **please** don't edit this file bit.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry to say, when you send a file by email, you strip away the [metadata](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23254/49368)  which would [enable read-only status](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/143040-how-send-email-attachment-read-only-linux.html) of the file itself.

An alternative approach using the Perl module [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX) to make the XLS or XLSX file 'Protected' will not modify an existing XLS or XLSX file, and [learning Perl](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_introduction) to generate the XLSX file instead of the existing [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) process is a non-trivial task which may be too much to ask.

That leaves creating a [macro in LibreOffice](https://oscollege.com/2018/03/05/libreoffice-offers-flexibility-for-programmers-by-allowing-macros-to-be-written-in-four-languages/) or [OpenOffice](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewforum.php?f=45) to open the file, [protect it](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Protecting_Cells_from_Changes), and close it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have file available in linux. But before sending an email i want to change the property. Is there any way..

Comment: I have perl installed in my system.

Comment: But the Perl module will not modify an existing XLS or XLSX file. You can't use Perl's Excel::Writer::XLSX module to do what you want unless you change your ETL process. I mentioned it only because a search would show it.  Therefore, see the third paragraph of my answer above.